# Maven Multi Module Project looking for modules in repository instead of Building them

Tags: maven

I have a multi-module MVN project, which has 1 aggregator pom, another parent pom, and 3 other modules, as follows:

project-all 
 -project-parent 
 -project-common
 -project-maintainance
 -project-webApp

project-WebApp has a dependency on project-common and project-maintenance.

When I run a clean install on project-all, it tries to download the modules from repositories instead of building them.

My understanding of a multi-module project is that it runs an install on all the modules as well, but that is not what is happening.

If I run a clean install on all the modules separately, the project-all clean install works fine. It also works when I run the mvn build in Eclipse with the Resolve Workspace Artifacts option selected.

However, both of these options are not viable options, since the idea of using a multi-module project is to run multiple poms from a single location.

Am I missing something, what would be the process of asking mvn to build those modules instead of looking for them in the repository.

Pom for project-all:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<groupId>com.midtier.api</groupId>
<artifactId>project-all</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<name>project-all</name>
<!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
<url>http://www.example.com</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>


<modules>
    <module>project-parent</module>
    <module>project-data</module>
    <module>project-maintenance</module>
    <module>project-WebApp</module>
</modules>
```

POM for project-parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.midtier.api</groupId>
<artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>


<name>${project.artifactId}</name>
<description>${project.artifactId}</description>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <elasticsearch.version>6.2.4</elasticsearch.version>
    <jsonsimple.version>1.1.1</jsonsimple.version>
    <slf4j-version>1.7.25</slf4j-version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
<!--Dependencies Here-->
</dependencyManagement>
```

Pom for project-Webapp:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.midtier.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.rbc.midtier.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-webapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>

    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>${project.artifactId}</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.midtier.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-data</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.midtier.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-maintenance</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

project-data and project-maintenance are similar to project-web app but they don't have any internal dependencies.

**Again, what I want to do is, just run the clean install command on all, and not have to worry about building any of the modules individually.**

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you define the parent as a module. When you run „clean“ the parent used by the other modules is still not available so Maven tries to find it within the repository. Better define the parent information within the project-all pom because during the build phase the parent has to be available.